# Heroku, Stopping all processes with SIGTERM, Process exited with status 143

Tags: node.js, heroku, backend

My backend was hosted on heroku for more than a month and was working fine. Now, today when I opened my web site it shows this error in heroku logs.

heroku logs

```
2022-11-26T13:59:37.770793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling    2022-11-26T13:59:37.773849+00:00 
2022-11-26T13:59:37.770793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling    2022-11-26T13:59:37.773849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting    2022-11-26T13:`your text`59:40.671794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start` `2022-11-26T13:59:43.453482+00:00 app\[web.1\]:\`
2022-11-26T13:59:43.453508+00:00 app\[web.1\]: \> server@1.0.0 start
2022-11-26T13:59:43.453508+00:00 app\[web.1\]: \> node index.js
2022-11-26T13:59:43.453509+00:00 app\[web.1\]:
2022-11-26T13:59:43.936570+00:00 app\[web.1\]: Server started successfully on port 28406
2022-11-26T13:59:44.394629+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from starting to up
2022-11-26T13:59:45.969634+00:00 app\[web.1\]: MongoDB Connected: ac-rbrrtx1-shard-00-02.hnnmtja.mongodb.net
2022-11-26T13:59:47.331529+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=info method=GET path="/todos" host=to-do.herokuapp.com request_id=498c9348-ac27-4d03-98c5-ed9650e5b6d3 fwd="74.125.215.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2501ms status=200 bytes=770 protocol=https
2022-11-26T14:35:38.862987+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Idling
2022-11-26T14:35:38.864646+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: State changed from up to down
2022-11-26T14:35:39.633081+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-11-26T14:35:39.834323+00:00 heroku\[web.1\]: Process exited with status 143
2022-12-02T12:31:11.037127+00:00 app\[api\]: Scaled to web@0:Eco by user api-maintenance@heroku.com
2022-12-08T18:34:07.067959+00:00 heroku\[router\]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=to-do.herokuapp.com request_id=c7c564c9-6334-4140-bf27-6b0750093c26 fwd="5.255.253.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https\`\`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would like to confirm whether you are using free plan of Heroku or not. Because Heroku stopped its free plan starting from November-26-2022.
For further information:
https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2022/09/13/heroku-free-tier-being-retired/

If you have a paid version then it's a problem associated with dynos as the error is giving code H14 (last line). This is most likely the result of scaling your web dynos down to 0 dynos. Scale up your dynos to fix it.
For more information visit Heroku error codes:
[Heroku error codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running)

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed using the free plan of Heroku. That was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted. If you want there are other free hosting platform available like Render, cyclic, Railways etc.. I prefer Render which is easy to deploy.